# Not able to add folders to with git on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I cloned few repo from the github into my current working direcory.
I forgot to delete the .git folder in their folder and i commited the changes.

Then i delete the .git folders inside them and again hit commit.

Now in my bitbucket account they are coming as greyout in grey color like this.
I can't click on them

```
demo_test1 → 3608f1e44d[36044c82d]
demo_test2 → 8cc44a089[8cc4a089]
```

All the files are still there in my local folders but not in bitbucket.

IF i hit commit it says no changes but files are still there.

what should i do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reset your HEAD and index back to before you added your nested repos:

```
git reset SHA1_before_first_commit_with_nest_git_repos
git add . 
git commit -m "nested repos clones"
git push -f
```

The `git reset` won't affect your current working directory (so your files remains untouched, and your nested repos, without their .git folder that you just removed, are still there).
After the reset, you can add all those files again, and force push that new commit back to BitBucket.

If you don't have many collaborator on that BitBucket repo, forcing the push (ie, replacing the published history by a  new one), won't be a problem.

Comment: how can i get SHA1 of that commit

Comment: @user a simple git log will show you all the commits you have done.

Comment: I am now getting the conflicts , it says that there are some directories on the server , it says cannot drop to stage #0

Comment: @user What command are you doing, and what exact error message are you getting? Considering I didn't mention git stage, you could detail that in a new question.

Comment: Actually i tried `push -u` instead of `push -f`. it was giving me error. now i tried push -f and it worked. thanks